# jQuery datepicker- 2 inputs/textboxes and restricting range

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using the jQuery Datepicker widget with two input boxes, one for the **"From"** date and the second with the **"To"** date. I am using the [jQuery Datepicker functional demo](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) as a basis for getting the two input boxes to work with each other, but I need to be able to add these additional restrictions:

1. Date range can be no earlier than
   01 December 2008
2. **"To"** date can be no
       later than today
3. Once a **"From"** date
       is selected, the **"To"** date can only
       be within a range of 7 days after
       the **"From"** date
4. If a **"To"** date is
       selected first, then the **"From"** date
       can only be within the range of 7
       days before the **"To"** date (with the
       limit of 01 December being the first
       selectable date)

I can't seem to get all of the above working together.

In summary, I would like to be able to select a range of up to 7 days between 01 December and today (I realise I am posting this on 1st December so will only get today for the moment).

My code so far

```
$(function () {

$('#txtStartDate, #txtEndDate').datepicker(
            {
            showOn: "both",
            beforeShow: customRange,
            dateFormat: "dd M yy",
            firstDay: 1, 
            changeFirstDay: false
            });
});

function customRange(input) 
{ 

return {
         minDate: (input.id == "txtStartDate" ? new Date(2008, 12 - 1, 1) : null),
         minDate: (input.id == "txtEndDate" ? $("#txtStartDate").datepicker("getDate") : null), 
         maxDate: (input.id == "txtStartDate" ? $("#txtEndDate").datepicker("getDate") : null)
       }; 
}
```

I'm missing the 7 day range restriction and also preventing a **"To"** date selection before 01 December 2008 or after today. Any help would be much appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Here is a nice article with examples: [End Date should not be less than Start Date using jQuery Date Picker](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/01/end-date-should-not-be-greater-than.html).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Many thanks for your help Ben, I have built upon your posts and have come up with this. It is now complete and works brilliantly!

Here's a **[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/evudo)**. Add **/edit** to the URL to see the code

Complete Code below-

```
$(function () 
{   
    $('#txtStartDate, #txtEndDate').datepicker({
        showOn: "both",
        beforeShow: customRange,
        dateFormat: "dd M yy",
        firstDay: 1, 
        changeFirstDay: false
    });

});

function customRange(input) { 
    var min = new Date(2008, 11 - 1, 1), //Set this to your absolute minimum date
        dateMin = min,
        dateMax = null,
        dayRange = 6; // Set this to the range of days you want to restrict to

    if (input.id === "txtStartDate") {
        if ($("#txtEndDate").datepicker("getDate") != null) {
            dateMax = $("#txtEndDate").datepicker("getDate");
            dateMin = $("#txtEndDate").datepicker("getDate");
            dateMin.setDate(dateMin.getDate() - dayRange);
            if (dateMin < min) {
                dateMin = min;
            }
        }
        else {
            dateMax = new Date; //Set this to your absolute maximum date
        }                      
    }
    else if (input.id === "txtEndDate") {
        dateMax = new Date; //Set this to your absolute maximum date
        if ($("#txtStartDate").datepicker("getDate") != null) {
            dateMin = $("#txtStartDate").datepicker("getDate");
            var rangeMax = new Date(dateMin.getFullYear(), dateMin.getMonth(),dateMin.getDate() + dayRange);

            if(rangeMax < dateMax) {
                dateMax = rangeMax; 
            }
        }
    }
    return {
        minDate: dateMin, 
        maxDate: dateMax
    };     
}
```

Answer (score 15):

I realise I'm a little late to the party, but here is how I modified the working example code. I didn't need to set a specific maximum and minimum date, just didn't want a date range overlap, so I just let them set each other:

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('#calendardatetime_required_to, #calendardatetime_required_from').datepicker('option', {
    beforeShow: customRange
  });
});

function customRange(input) {
  if (input.id == 'calendardatetime_required_to') {
    return {
      minDate: jQuery('#calendardatetime_required_from').datepicker("getDate")
    };
  } else if (input.id == 'calendardatetime_required_from') {
    return {
      maxDate: jQuery('#calendardatetime_required_to').datepicker("getDate")
    };
  }
}
```

(My datepickers were already initialised in a script further up, but it's just default settings.)

Seems to do what I need it to :)

See [here](http://jsbin.com/evudo/26) for my example.

Comment: Lovely. Exactly what I was looking for ;)

Answer (score 14):

Alright, how about this:

```
function customRange(input) 
{ 
    var min = new Date(2008, 12 - 1, 1);
    var dateMin = min;
    var dateMax = null;

    if (input.id == "txtStartDate" && $("#txtEndDate").datepicker("getDate") != null)
    {
        dateMax = $("#txtEndDate").datepicker("getDate");
        dateMin = $("#txtEndDate").datepicker("getDate");
        dateMin.setDate(dateMin.getDate() - 7);
        if (dateMin < min)
        {
            dateMin = min;
        }           
    }
    else if (input.id == "txtEndDate")
    {
        dateMax = new Date();
        if ($("#txtStartDate").datepicker("getDate") != null)
        {
            dateMin = $("#txtStartDate").datepicker("getDate");
            dateMax = $("#txtStartDate").datepicker("getDate");
            dateMax.setDate(dateMax.getDate() + 7); 
        }
    }
    return {
     minDate: dateMin, 
     maxDate: dateMax
   }; 

}
```

This is the best I could come up with that met all of your requirements (I think...)

Answer (score 4):

Consider using rangeSelect to have one control instead of two.

To achieve what you are after, I suppose you need to add an onSelect listener and then call `datepicker( "option", settings )` to change the settings.

Comment: Using one control is a possiblity, although I'd prefer to try and keep the "From and "To" dates in separate controls to maintain the current UI consistency.

Answer (score 4):

Your start date for txtStartDate isn't working because your second minDate is being set to null when it checks the input.id the second time.  Also, maxDate should be checking for txtEndDate, not txtStartDate.  Try this:

```
    function customRange(input) 
{ 
    var mDate = (input.id == "txtStartDate" ? new Date(2008, 12 - 1, 1) : $("#txtStartDate").datepicker("getDate"));
    return {
         minDate: mDate, 
         maxDate: (input.id == "txtEndDate" ? $("#txtStartDate").datepicker("getDate").getDate() + 5 : null)
       }; 
}
```

I don't know why the '+ 5' instead of '+ 7', but if I add 0, I get a selectable date range of the day I picked plus the next.

Comment: This solves the selectable range of 7 days from "From" date to "To" date but it errors if selecting a "To" date before a "From" date has been selected.

Comment: Yeah, I missed some of your requirements on the first pass.  See my other answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution I came up with after a lot of digging for a solution to what I think is a common problem.  This effectively 'bounces' the inputs around a shared input range of compatible days.  Meaning - if I have two fields, either one can be used to constrain the other, and the other could redefine the original if necessary.  The goal of this is to always ensure that there is only a finite range of days (or months or whatever) between the the two fields.  This specific example also limits the amount of time into the future that something could be selected in either field (e.g. 3 months).

```
$("#startdate").datepicker({
   minDate: '+5', 
   maxDate: '+3M',
   changeMonth: true,
   showAnim: 'blind',
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst){ 

    // Capture the Date from User Selection
    var oldDate = new Date(dateText);
    var newDate = new Date(dateText);

    // Compute the Future Limiting Date
    newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate()+5);


    // Set the Widget Properties
    $("#enddate").datepicker('option', 'minDate', oldDate);
    $("#enddate").datepicker('option', 'maxDate', newDate);

    }
  });

 $("#enddate").datepicker({
  minDate: '+5',
  maxDate: '+3M',
  changeMonth: true,
  showAnim: 'blind', 
  onSelect: function(dateText, inst){ 

    // Capture the Date from User Selection
    var endDate = new Date(dateText);
    var startDate = new Date(dateText);

    // Compute the Future Limiting Date
    startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate()-5);

    // Set the Widget Properties
    $("#startdate").datepicker('option', 'minDate', startDate);
    $("#startdate").datepicker('option', 'maxDate', endDate);

    }

  });
```

Answer (score 3):

this is how i use it:

```
function customRange(input)
{
    var min = new Date();
    return {
        minDate: ((input.id == "txtStartDate") ? min : (input.id == "txtEndDate" ? $("#txtStartDate").datepicker("getDate") : null)),
        maxDate: (input.id == "txtStartDate" ? $("#txtEndDate").datepicker("getDate") : null)
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have done it. I have taken the source from the Jquery UI website and modified it to add your constraints.

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{      
  var dates = $('#StartDate, #EndDate').datepicker({
        minDate: new Date(2008, 11, 1), 
        maxDate: "+0D",
        dateFormat: "dd M yy",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        onSelect: function (selectedDate)
        {
            var option = this.id == "StartDate" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
                instance = $(this).data("datepicker"),
                date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                    instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                    $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                    selectedDate, instance.settings);
            var edate;
            var otherOption;
            var d;
            if (option == "minDate")
            {
                otherOption = "maxDate";
                d = date.getDate() + 7;
            }
            else if (option == "maxDate")
            {
                otherOption = "minDate";
                d = date.getDate() - 7;
            }

            var m = date.getMonth();
            var y = date.getFullYear();
            edate = new Date(y, m, d);

            dates.not(this).datepicker("option", option, date);
            dates.not(this).datepicker("option", otherOption, edate);
        }
    });
});
```

Initial Idea from: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-range

**Note:** You would also need an option to reset/clear the dates (i.e. if a user chooses a 'From date', the 'To date' becomes limited. After choosing a 'From date' if the user now chooses a 'To date', the From date also gets limited. You need to have a clear option to allow the user to choose a different "From" date now.)