# How to set a Jquery Datepicker daterange

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I have two input text boxes which is bound to jquery Datepicker widget.
When user select a given date from Date1 (Effective Date), I want to set the min date  of Date2 (Expiry date) to Date1 + 1 .. How do I do that,
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see this link :
[jQuery datepicker- 2 inputs/textboxes and restricting range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330737/jquery-datepicker-2-inputs-textboxes-and-restricting-range)

and use `onChangeMonthYear` function or `onSelect` function:

```
$('#txtStartDate, #txtEndDate').datepicker({
        showOn: "both",
        beforeShow: customRange,
        dateFormat: "dd M yy",
        firstDay: 1, 
        changeFirstDay: false,
        onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) { ... },
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { ... }
    });
```

and use the same technique  **Ben Koehler** or **Russ Cam** used.