# Filter values in date pickers in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JQuery datepicker- 2 inputs/textboxes and restricting range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330737/jquery-datepicker-2-inputs-textboxes-and-restricting-range)

Hi i have two pickers in a page

```
$(function() {

    $( "#d1" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});});



$(function() {

    $( "#d2" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});});
```

what i required is to be always `#d2 > #d1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible duplicate of this post. Answer is perfect and educational: [jQuery datepicker- 2 inputs/textboxes and restricting range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330737/jquery-datepicker-2-inputs-textboxes-and-restricting-range)

Comment: If it's a dupe, you might as well mark it as a dupe and vote to close it. The link to the original question will be added for you.