# Jquery calender 2 way block date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, calendar

I am using jquery ui date selector
My query is different from all other asked as i need 2 custom methods to block date

```
    <script>
        var unavailableDates = ["5-7-2011","6-7-2011","7-7-2011","15-7-2011","16-7-2011","17-7-2011" ];


function unavailable(date) {
  dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
  if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
    return [true, ""];
  } else {
    return [false,"","Unavailable"];
  }
}
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker_1,#datepicker_2" ).datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: unavailable,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
});
```

i have customized my code to disable few date , which i took refernce for also, but also i want the  other date selector to have date set according to first
for eg for selector 2(which is max date) i select 4th july, than the selectot 1 should have date greater than today but less than4th july... if i select from selector1 (which is min date) 1st july it should disable all previous date ...

My problem is similar to [jQuery datepicker- 2 inputs/textboxes and restricting range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330737/jquery-datepicker-2-inputs-textboxes-and-restricting-range) but a step ahead where i need to disable some date as above

Any help will hugely be appreciated as i am new bee in jquery

[here is jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rigids/uGgj7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {      $( "#datepicker_1,#datepicker_2" ).datepicker({
             beforeShow: customRange,           beforeShowDay: unavailable,             changeMonth: true,          changeYear: true        });     });         function customRange(input) {   if (input.id == 'datepicker_2') {
    return {
      minDate: jQuery('#datepicker_1').datepicker("getDate")
    };   } else if (input.id == 'datepicker_1') {
    return {
      maxDate: jQuery('#datepicker_2').datepicker("getDate")
    };   } }
```

Try this if it helps you

Comment: Is this possible to stop overlapping blocked date , for eg 14th is blocked and user selects 12th date and try to set 16th as end date
see it overlaps 14th already blocked date.....

Comment: I have updated my fiddle with your code. thanks for help can you help me more? 
15,16,17 are blocked if a user selects 14 as start date and 18 as end this overlaps blocked date can you see if it can be done to stop overlapping block date and show an alert