# JQuery calender to highlight current week and block 3 weeks

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

I'm using jquery calender in one of my application and what I need to do is once I select a date between day Mon - Fri then entire Mon-Fri days should get highlight and also 3 weeks considering only from Mon - Fri gets greyed out.

I tired to get some good input from already posted query but none was helpfull. I took help from post [Jquery calender 2 way block date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534099/jquery-calender-2-way-block-date) but was difficult to implement.

I need a some code snippet to understand how to validate over calender days.

Thanks

Comment: Removed jquery-ajax & MVC tags. Also, post some of your code so people have something to work with!

Comment: Please provide code or jsfiddle