# jQuery Datepicker beforeShowDay - range selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datepicker

I'm doing a website for an hotel, and I'm trying to do a datepicker to book the days that somebody wants to stay there.

http://jsfiddle.net/newpatriks/PmPGV/

Here you have that I have done, but I've some problems:

1. I don't know why, but when the users select the range days, the calendar starts from the month that contains the "end day" choosen.
2. The css run ok for the .temp_1, but not going well for the .temp_2 and .date_selected (I'm going crazy about this...)

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Please just use comments under the answers you receive to leave comments. Answers are reserved for just that, answers to the question at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery Datepicker has a built in range select: [datepicker/date-range](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/date-range.html).

[Here](http://jsbin.com/evudo) is an example from the following question: [jQuery datepicker- 2 inputs/textboxes and restricting range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330737/jquery-datepicker-2-inputs-textboxes-and-restricting-range)

Comment: but this solutions is for two inputs (two differents calendars). I need to do it with only one calendar... :S