# Datepicker - automatically assign second date X days later

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I don't really get how to code my two datepickers. When I select a certain date with the first datepicker, I want the second one to automatically select a date X days after. The following code is what I have now. What's left to do?

```
$(function() {
        $.datepicker.setDefaults({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', 
        firstDay: 1,
        showOn: "both",
        buttonImage: "/images/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true});
      $('#txtStartDate').datepicker({minDate: 0, onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
            var minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            if (minDate) {
                  minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 1);
            }
            $('#txtEndDate').datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate || 1); // Date + 1 or tomorrow by default
      }});
      $('#txtEndDate').datepicker({minDate: 1, onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
            var maxDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            if (maxDate) {
                  maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate() - 1);
            }
            $('#txtStartDate').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', maxDate); // Date - 1
      }});
});
```

Comment: Where do you define/figure what `X` is?

Comment: you want to assign date to enddate then you can directly assign  var 
        var toDate =startdate.getMonth()+1+"/"+ startdate.getDate()+noofdays) + '/' + date.getFullYear();

Comment: If you want some help with this you at least need to tell us what is wrong. What is the current code doing. If it is doing nothing then you need to say this. Also, a JSFiddle would be most helpful too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help, cheers!

Link: [jQuery datepicker- 2 inputs/textboxes and restricting range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330737/jquery-datepicker-2-inputs-textboxes-and-restricting-range)

Working Demo : http://jsbin.com/evudo but you can find out more options in the link above.

link : http://forum.jquery.com/topic/2-datepickers-start-end-date-get-and-post

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
jQuery(function($){
    $(".urDatePickerName").datepicker({ 
        dateFormat   :  'yy-mm-dd'
    });
});

function validate (){
      var dateFrom = $('#start1').val();
      var dateTo = $('#end1').val();
      if(dateFrom > dateTo){
       alert('Invalid date entry, "date from" is greater than "date to".');
      }else{
           //customRange .. you can find in the URL Code...
     }
}
</script>
```